# Strings in Switch Statements: 'String' does not conform to protocol 'IntervalType'

Tags: string, swift, switch-statement

I am having problems using strings in switch statements in Swift.

I have a dictionary called `opts` which is declared as `<String, AnyObject>`

I have this code:

```
switch opts["type"] {
case "abc":
    println("Type is abc")
case "def":
    println("Type is def")
default:
    println("Type is something else")
}
```

and on the lines `case "abc"` and `case "def"` I get the following error:

```
Type 'String' does not conform to protocol 'IntervalType'
```

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This error is shown when an optional is used in a switch statement.
Simply unwrap the variable and everything should work.

```
switch opts["type"]! {
  case "abc":
    println("Type is abc")
  case "def":
    println("Type is def")
  default:
    println("Type is something else")
}
```

Edit:
In case you don't want to do a forced unwrapping of the optional, you can use `guard`. Reference: [Control Flow: Early Exit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html)

Comment: Added the answer with alternative and _safer_ solution below.

Comment: don't use this! The value is marked optional in it's own reason, a nil value will crash your app. @mikejd offered a much better answer

Comment: @Lcsky I have updated the answer to use `guard` if you are not sure of the value in `opts`.

Comment: This dangerous because if the optional is nil then the program will crash!

Comment: You should never use ! directly like here, so potential crash. It is forbidden if you use SwiftLint for example. I prefer mikejd solution.

Comment: Honestly, it is so lame that Swift cannot handle optional values in switch statements. As others say, this is actually quite dangerous and requires extra boilerplate code to make it safe, when the language could be a little smarter and make this a lot easier.

Answer (score 39):

According to [Swift Language Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-ID452):

> The type Optional is an enumeration with two cases, None and Some(T), which are used to represent values that may or may not be present.

So under the hood an optional type looks like this:

```
enum Optional<T> {
  case None
  case Some(T)
}
```

This means that you can go *without* forced unwrapping:

```
switch opts["type"] {
case .Some("A"):
  println("Type is A")
case .Some("B"):
  println("Type is B")
case .None:
  println("Type not found")
default:
  println("Type is something else")
}
```

This may be safer, because the app won't crash if `type` were not found in `opts` dictionary.

Comment: this is probably the best answer, but I dont do app development anymore, so I have no way of testing this.

Comment: the best answer indeed!

Comment: You have been hit by the friendly Swift 3 renaming goblin: .Some has been renamed to .some (which luckily the Swift 3 compiler ant has been happy to tell you :-). Still the best answer, thanks (even more if you return for a Swift 3 version).

Answer (score 17):

Try using:

```
let str:String = opts["type"] as String
switch str {
case "abc":
    println("Type is abc")
case "def":
    println("Type is def")
default:
    println("Type is something else")
}
```

Comment: just tried both of these, and both still give me the error `Type 'String' does not conform to protocol 'IntervalType'`

Comment: What kind of dictionary is `opts`?

Comment: I tried both versions and with this `var opts = ["type": "Type is abc"]` it works in a playground

Comment: `opts` is `<String, AnyObject>`

Comment: `case let string as String where string == "abc":` gives the error `Type 'String' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'`

Comment: ok, Ive figured it out - before the switch I do `let str:String = opts["type"] as String` and then I perform the switch (pretty much as I had it in my original question) on `str` instead. @Kirsteins you helped me to get to where I needed, so if you update your questions with a solution like this I will mark you as correct.

Answer (score 13):

I had this same error message inside `prepareForSegue()`, which I imagine is fairly common. The error message is somewhat opaque but the answers here got me on the right track. If anyone encounters this, you don't need any typecasting, just a conditional unwrap around the switch statement:-

```
if let segueID = segue.identifier {
    switch segueID {
        case "MySegueIdentifier":
            // prepare for this segue
        default:
            break
    }
}
```

Comment: A `guard` statement also works well inside `prepareForSegue()`: `guard let segueID = segue.identifier else { return }`

Answer (score 6):

Instead of the unsafe force unwrap.. I find it easier to test for the optional case:

```
switch opts["type"] {
  case "abc"?:
    println("Type is abc")
  case "def"?:
    println("Type is def")
  default:
    println("Type is something else")
}
```

(See added **?** to the case)