# String does not conform to protocol "intervalType"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I got the error

> Type 'String' does not conform to protocol 'intervalType'

I tried this code only in a playgroundfile and it doesn't work also.

```
var header = [String:AnyObject]()

header["NachrichtenTyp"] = "2001"

switch header["NachrichtenTyp"] {
case "2001":
    println("2001 Import new file")

default:
    break 
}
```

I found this thread: [Strings in Switch Statements: 'String' does not conform to protocol 'IntervalType'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26865132/strings-in-switch-statements-string-does-not-conform-to-protocol-intervaltyp)

But this example also don't work on my playground (Xcode 6.2)

Comment: what happens if you try let myString: String = header["NachrichtenTyp"] and then switch the myString?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to type `as String` many times in case of lot of different values, you can nest two `switch` statements like this:

```
var header: [String:AnyObject] = [:]

header["NachrichtenTyp"] = "2001"

for key in header.keys {

  switch header[key] {

    case let str as String:
      switch str {
        case "2001":
          println("2001 Import new file")
        default:
          break
      }

    case let num as Int:
      // ...
      break

    default:
      break
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this by:

```
case "2001" as String:
    println("2001 Import new file")
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify like this :

```
var header: [String:AnyObject] = [:]

header["NachrichtenTyp"] = "2001" ;

if let header = header["NachrichtenTyp"] as? NSString
{
    switch header
    {
        case "2001":
        println("2001 Import new file")
        break

    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can cast your "NachrichtenTyp". So you dont need to "as string" each case-statement:

```
    var header: [String:String] = [:]

    header["NachrichtenTyp"] = "2001"

    let ntype:String = header["NachrichtenTyp"]! as String

    switch ntype {
    case "2001":
        println("2001 Import new file")

    default:
        break 
    }
```

Comment: This will only work for strings and not `AnyObject`.

Comment: Indeed. I understood the presented code of the questioner that way regarding his case-statement to use AnyObject accidentally instead of String. My fault :)